# Using feather icons with variables in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display an icon that has its name stored in a variable.

The solution bellow doesn't work but it exemplifies what I'm trying to achieve here.

```
import React from "react"
import * as Icon from "react-feather"

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const iconName = "Search";
    return (
      <>
        <Icon id={iconName} />
      </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Well if your Icon component accepts id with name of an icon then your solution should work

Comment: @EvgenyKlimenchenko It's not a component, forgot to add that bit of code

Comment: I answered, hope it works for you, I've tested it works for me

Comment: It works, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, Icon is an object and you can just take the key of the icon

```js
import * as Icon from 'react-feather'

render() {
 const label = 'Search'
 const Search = Icon[label]
 return (
  <>
    <Search />
  </>
 )
}
```